# DNS record updated in Azure Domain settings not showing up in digwebinterface.com

Tags: azure, dns

I was trying to get SSL (Wildcard) from `sslforfree.com`,
I have updated my DNS settings and added TXT records for two of my domains.

However, [DigWeb](http://digwebinterface.com) cannot find the record with host/name as `_acme-challenge.domain.com` and `_acme-challenge.domain2.com`, nor `sslforfree.com` website is able to verify the domains.

**Update** :

[image]

See the **DNS** settings in above screenshot.

Comment: In your domain2.com, there is an A record for _acme-challenge?

Comment: No, in both the domains I've added  TXT Records

Comment: I'm digging both the domains separately for TXT DNS records.

Comment: Any update in this case?

Comment: Not seeing any of my _acme-challenge.domain.com TXT records in [DigWeb](https://digwebinterface.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should make sure you type the correct TXT record format in your DNS setting under the `domain.com` zone in your domain provider. When you apply for a free SSL certificate on the sslforfree.com. You need to add TXT records with host/name `_acme-challenge.domain.com` with a valid value and a TTL (in seconds) of 1. Then you can verify `_acme-challenge.domain.com`. You may have to wait a minute or a couple minutes for the DNS TXT record to propagate if the TTL record value does not show up or is not the same as the above values.

Here is a screenshot of TXT record adding in `domain.com` zone in Azure-DNS.

[image]

Moreover, if your domains do not point to a DNS server then you must point it to one beforehand. That is to say, an NS record should exist in the zone `domain.com`. You also need to confirm that your domain can be resolved publicly.

If all above is not working. You can check if CNAME records exist in your `domain.com`, you can remove all the CNAME records as you can not have a CNAME record for `domain.com` since there are obviously NS and SOA records for it already, which is incompatible with a CNAME presence. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616455/unable-to-set-txt-record-to-domain-in-freenom-provider/52621619#52621619).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do have `NS` record in my domain and [DigWeb](https://digwebinterface.com) is able to resolve one txt record with Name Servers. Also a question, As a host/name should I only specify _acme-challenge or _acme-challenge.domain.com?

Comment: You only specify _acme-challenge as a name of TXT record and value with the valid token (which is given from sslforfree.com) inside your specific domain.com zone.

Comment: From your screenshot, you have to change the TXT record name to _acme-challenge in the domain.com. If you have domain2.com, you should add another TXT record name _acme-challenge with its valid token inside the domain2.com. Also, suggest setting the TTL as 1 second to verify domains.

Comment: changed TXT records as suggested, also Azure Domains Management allows TTL to be set more than or equals to 600 seconds not less, so I'll have to wait till DNS Propagation.

Comment: Waited for long, still don't see any TXT records in DigWeb.

Comment: Can you remove the CNAMEs to see if TXT verify? You also can add CNAMEs back after the TXT verify pass.

Comment: removed CNAMEs with no luck, Also for testing I added a TXT record with name as @ and value as something.azurewebsites.net before removing any CNAME record, and it did reflect in DigWeb, not sure why this one is not reflecting...

Comment: What about the steps 3: verify your domain in sslforfree.com?

Comment: Verified domain in sslforfree.com, worked.
Solutions was to remove all CNAME records from DNS Settings.
Thanks, also suggest you to update your answer with this solution.

Comment: Ha, I mentioned removing CNAMEs. Perhaps it's not clear. Glad to hear it worked.:)