# Unable to set TXT record to domain in Freenom provider

Tags: azure, ssl, dns

I would like to enable SSL for my domain assigned to the wordpress in Azure.
My domain is created in Freenom. 
To finish the process I need to manually verify the domain from Azure:

[Azure Domain Verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4park.jpg)

Then I created TXT record in my domain in Freenom:

[Freenom provider settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X83Rw.jpg)

But the TXT record is not created:

```
$ dig nemoz.ml TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-61.el7 <<>> nemoz.ml TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29489
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; MBZ: 0005 , udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nemoz.ml.          IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nemoz.ml.       5   IN  CNAME   nemoz.azurewebsites.net.
nemoz.azurewebsites.net. 5  IN  CNAME   waws-prod-am2-203.sip.azurewebsites.windows.net.
waws-prod-am2-203.sip.azurewebsites.windows.net. 5 IN CNAME waws-prod-am2-203.cloudapp.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cloudapp.net.       5   IN  SOA prd1.azuredns-cloud.net. msnhst.microsoft.com.cloudapp.net. 2110897293 900 300 604800 60

;; Query time: 299 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.47.2#53(192.168.47.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 02 16:56:54 EDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 250
```

And I am not able to verify the domain from Azure. I tried many configurations in Freenom, using networking tools, and searched many web pages. And nothing working.
Can you please help me find the problem?

Comment: Just as a test, does anything change if you remove CNAME record for nemoz.ml?

Comment: Start by doing a `dig` query towards the authoritative nameserver not the cache one, but anyway that is an invalid zone as you can not have a `CNAME` record for `nemoz.ml` since there are obviously `NS` and `SOA` records for it already, which is incompatible with a `CNAME` presence. See all problems found at http://dnsviz.net/d/nemoz.ml/dnssec/

Comment: It works, I removed CNAME, thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works! 
I removed CNAMEs from Freenom and now I get TXT record:

```
$ dig nemoz.ml TXT

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-61.el7 <<>> nemoz.ml TXT
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26447
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; MBZ: 0005 , udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nemoz.ml.          IN  TXT

;; ANSWER SECTION:
nemoz.ml.       5   IN  TXT "phkg1hlljofbujbrfvl8pe8l62"
nemoz.ml.       5   IN  TXT "nemoz.azurewebsites.net"

;; Query time: 1677 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.47.2#53(192.168.47.2)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 03 03:33:42 EDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 112
```

Also in Azure the domain verification is successful. Thanks a lot.

**But the question is why is that? Why CNAME record prevents TXT record in domain?**

Comment: "Why CNAME record prevents TXT record in domain?" That is not the true question/problem. A `CNAME` can not exist at apex, that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you type the correct TXT record format in your domain DNS zone. named **@** with a valid value `ph*********62`in Freenom provider. And wait a few minuies for DNS propagation.

Here is an example in Azure DNS.

[image]

Comment: "And wait a few minuies for DNS propagation." that can be hours or days, depending on many factors, as it is not reall a top down propagation case but a more complicated scenarios of caches being renewed after some "time to live".

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  yes, I agree, Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In Freenom replace `1examplevalue1` with the token `ph*********62`.

Comment: 1examplevalue1 is just a dummy text, in Freenom there is a valid code.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem can be that you have two TXT records with the same value.
For some reason it causes a conflict and records won't take effect.